# Don't know how to change the download destination of /tmp from FireFox

Tags: firefox

I recently just got Ubuntu 17.04 for my ASUS laptop and I noticed that all downloads go to /tmp folder in the root destination. I have dualbooted so this annoys me a lot and the files that are in there are usually locked, so I may need help with that too. I'm more of a Windows user so I am still learning about Linux... Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Open Firefox.

Click the menu button on the far right-hand side near the top (it looks like 3 horizontal lines).

Click preferences.

You should see "Downloads" "Save file to: ", you can use the "browse" button to find the folder you would like downloads to save to.

Comment: You can also access the settings by typing `about:preferences` in the URL bar

Comment: this didn't fix the issue for me. no matter what I change the value to it always downloads files to /tmp. is it because of the new SNAP packaging?